# Ruby Regex solution for 3 types of strings

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to grab the first part of a string. 
Three types of cases I need to match are:

1. The Jones Group
2. Amanda Jones,
3. William Smith, Director

I only want to grab the name(The Jones Group, Amanda Jones, and William Smith) not the comma or anything after the comma. Sometimes a name will be present with a comma and nothing after it. Other time just a group name is used (i.e. The Stanley Team).

I've used

> /^(\w.+),.+/

but this fails for cases 1) and 2)

I've also tried

> /(\w.+)?,/

but this fails for 1)

Comment: Your description is vague regarding what you want to match. Two names in a row, each of them starting with a capital letter followed by lowercase letters and separated by a space? Can just one name by itself be valid? Maybe just anything after `'` until either another `'` or a `,`?

Comment: Use the character class `[^,]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to match all 3:

```
^([\w ]+)?,?.*$
```

Notice that there is a space in the `[ ]` to match the space between the names instead of all characters - otherwise, it would take in "Director" into the capture group as well.